# AssignFile(): File access denied

Tags: file, delphi

I want to create a `.txt` file and write to it at any moment at run-time. To do this, I'm using the `AssignFile()` function. But I am having trouble in instances where my file already exists. I get an error that says: **File access denied**.

To better explain, see these two examples:

**Ex1:** if I call `AssignFile()` the first time when the file does not exist, OK! But, if the file exists, this does not work.

**Ex2:** if I call `AssignFile()` the second time (when `AssignFile()` was successful the first time), this also does not work.

Is this a bug in the `AssignFile()` function?

```
var
  myfile: TextFile;

  Procedure WriteFileContent(const MyTxtFile: string; MyNumber: DWORD);
  var
    F: TextFile;
  Begin
    If FileExists(MyTxtFile) Then
    Begin
      AssignFile(F, MyTxtFile);
      Rewrite(F);
      Writeln(F, '0x' + IntToHex(MyNumber,8));
      CloseFile(F);
    End;
  End;

begin
  try

    // Calling AssignFile() by first time
    AssignFile(myfile, 'myfile.txt');
    Rewrite(myfile);
    CloseFile(myfile);
    setfileattributes('myfile.txt', FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);

    Sleep(5000);

    // Calling AssignFile() by second time
    WriteFileContent('myfile.txt', 123456789);

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Why aren't you specifying a full path for the file?

Comment: @MartynA, even if use `ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'myfile.txt'` error still persists.

Comment: So?  If you are trying to debug a problem like this, you should be ensuring that you are working with the same file each time, not just assuming that you are..

Comment: You are clearly trying to access a file that you do not have access to. For instance, if your program is installed in `C:\Program Files` and is trying to access a file in the app's folder, then standard users do not have write access to it.  You should be writing files to a folder in the user's profile instead.  The Win32 API have functions for determining the location of the user's profile.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, in any place that file is located, the trouble is the same :-(.

Comment: @MarcioGomes: that is not possible given the code you have shown. Unless you are running the app as a VERY restricted user who doesn't have write access to ANYTHING. Always use absolute paths, and make sure your user has write access to it.

Comment: Is this a bug? No, the error is in your understanding. Don't assume any failures are bugs. Look in the mirror first.

Comment: If someone test the code above, will see exactly: **File access denied**, even if change location of file.

Comment: So what happens if you remove the line `setfileattributes('myfile.txt', FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);`?

Comment: @TomBrunberg, works! :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not `AssignFile()` that fails, but your call to `Rewrite()` on a file with the `Hidden` attribute set. Following explains it:

Typically you call `Rewrite(F)` in order to erase the file and write new data to it with subsequent `Write(F, ...)` or `WriteLn(F, ...)` calls.

From docs (System.Rewrite):

> If an external file with the same name already exists, it is deleted
>   and a new empty file is created in its place.

There is no problem opening the file for writing with the `Append()` command.

(Based on above I drew the conclusion that it is the deletion that fails with the *Access denied* message. That was cutting the corners too much.)

---

Beaten by comments I traced through the code and compared actual code with MSDN documentation for CreateFile:

Actual code:

```
// if mode is fmOutput (as it is for Rewrite)
OpenMode = GENERIC_WRITE
Flags = CREATE_ALWAYS
// ...
Temp := CreateFile(t.Name, OpenMode, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, Flags, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
```

And [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If CREATE_ALWAYS and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL are specified, CreateFile
>   fails and sets the last error to ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED if the file
>   exists and has the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN or FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM
>   attribute.

Calling `Rewrite()` on a existing file with the `hidden` attribute fails always.

Comment: That seems a little implausible. Why would there be a call to DeleteFile? Surely it would be CreateFile with appropriate flags. And why would deleting hidden files be blocked?

Comment: @David I never said it calls DeleteFile, I just repeated what the docs for Rewrite says. But you forced me to trace deeper, thanks for that.

Comment: Well, you said "If it exists, it is deleted, recreated and opened for writing." But as I indicated, it is not deleted. A single call to CreateFile does the work. Thanks for digging out the docs for the hidden attribute behaviour.